# How to use mutiple values in input parameters in soap call

Tags: soap

I have a current requirement where I need to make a soap call to retrieve the data for further business intelligence. I have no experience in SOAP.

The service call is called getSiteInfo.

getSiteInfo has following 4 parameters- userName, password, custNbr, siteId.

Now I can make calls like this and it generates an xml response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bil="http://billing.xyz.cc/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <bil:getSiteInfo>
     <!--userName:-->
     <arg0>username</arg0>
     <!--password:-->
     <arg1>pswd</arg1>
     <!--custNbr:-->
     <arg2>288</arg2>
     <!--siteId:-->
     <arg3>0862578</arg3>
     
  </bil:getSiteInfo>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[image: soapcall]

I was wondering is it possible to include multiple siteId in the same call instead of doing it repeatedly for almost 1000+ siteIds.

I tried the following two to see if they work and none of them did. It only returned the response for the last item; 108952 in this case.

Method1

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bil="http://billing.xyz.cc/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <bil:getSiteInfo>
     <!--userName:-->
     <arg0>username</arg0>
     <!--password:-->
     <arg1>pswd</arg1>
     <!--customerNumber:-->
     <arg2>288</arg2>
     <!--siteNumber:-->
     <arg3>0862578</arg3>
     <arg3>108952</arg3>       
  </bil:getSiteInfo>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Method2

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bil="http://billing.xyz.cc/">
<soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
   <bil:getSiteInfo>
     <!--userName:-->
     <arg0>username</arg0>
     <!--password:-->
     <arg1>pswd</arg1>
     <!--customerNumber:-->
     <arg2>288</arg2>
     <!--siteNumber:-->     
     <arg3>108952</arg3>       
  </bil:getSiteInfo>
  <bil:getSiteInfo>
     <!--userName:-->
     <arg0>username</arg0>
     <!--password:-->
     <arg1>pswd</arg1>
     <!--customerNumber:-->
     <arg2>288</arg2>
     <!--siteNumber:-->
     <arg3>0862578</arg3>          
  </bil:getSiteInfo>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: no you cannot, there is a contract that specifies the layout of the message that you need to send. you need to commit to that contract. single side changes will result into error messages.

Comment: Thank for the response and clarification. I realized that after confirming that with service provider to understand if they have such provision on the call.